# How to write a dataset every N iterations using HDF5 in C++

Tags: c++, dataset, hdf5, montecarlo

I am writing a Monte Carlo code of a membrane, and I want to use HDF5 to export the data that contains the heights of every lattice site.

Following the examples on the documentation, I am able to write the height field in a dataset, and export it as a .h5 file. Note that the height field is a class representing a 2D mesh (or matrix if you prefer). The implementation is such that the 2D mesh is stored in a 1D array.

Now I want to be able to plot the membrane surface for a few time steps. How can I append the height field of a next time step to the existing file?

I know my question is somewhat generic and involves no code, so I expect answers that suggest what to look for. For example, are groups what I must look into? Or the so-called slabs? Any advice on where to search are appreciable.

EDIT:

Following the example on the documentation page, I have written the following code.

```
int main()
{
  /* Initialize field */
  int N_x = 6;
  int N_y = 6;
  int N_ghost = 2;
  Mesh2D sfield(N_x,N_y,N_ghost);
  
  /* Prepare */
  hsize_t rows = N_y + 2*N_ghost; //write the ghost zones as well
  hsize_t cols = N_x + 2*N_ghost;
  
  hsize_t dims[2] = {rows,cols}; // data set dimensions at creation (10X10)
  hsize_t maxdims[2] = {H5S_UNLIMITED, H5S_UNLIMITED};
  hsize_t chunk_dims[2] = {rows,cols};

  /* Variables for extending and writing to the extended portion of the dataset */
  hsize_t size[2];
  size[0] = rows;
  size[1] = cols;
  hsize_t offset[2];
  offset[0] = 0;
  offset[1] = 0;
  hsize_t dimsext[2] = {rows,cols}; //extend dimensions

  /*Try block to detect exceptions raised by any of the calls inside it */
  try{
    // Turn off the auto-printing when failure occurs so that we can
    // handle the errors appropriately
    Exception::dontPrint();

    // Create a new file using the default property lists.
    H5File file(FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_TRUNC);

    // Create the data space for the dataset. Note the use of pointer
    // for the instance 'dataspace'. It can be deleted and used again
    // later for another dataspace. An HDF5 identifier can be closed
    // by the destructor or the method 'close()'.
    DataSpace *dataspace = new DataSpace(2, dims, maxdims);

    // Modify dataset creation property to enable chunking
    DSetCreatPropList prop;
    prop.setChunk(2, chunk_dims);

    // Create the chunked dataset. Note the use of pointer.
    DataSet *dataset =
    new DataSet(file.createDataSet(DATASETNAME, PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE, *dataspace, prop));

    // Start iterations.
    DataSpace *filespace;
    DataSpace *memspace;
    int maxiter = 5;
    for (int iter = 0; iter<maxiter; iter++)
      {
    
    // Change the values of the field.
    sfield.meshfill(iter+1);
    
    // Extend the dataset. Dataset becomes 20 x 10, 30 x 10, etc.
    size[0] += dimsext[0];
    size[1] = dims[1];
    dataset->extend(size);

    // Select a hyperslab in extended portion of the dataset.
    filespace = new DataSpace(dataset->getSpace());
    offset[0] = iter*rows;
    filespace->selectHyperslab(H5S_SELECT_SET, dimsext, offset);

    // Define memory space.
    memspace = new DataSpace(2, dimsext, NULL);
    
    // Write data to the extended portion of the dataset.
    dataset->write(sfield.getmemory(), PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE, *memspace, *filespace);

    delete filespace;
    delete memspace;
      }
    
    // Close all objects and file.
    prop.close();
    delete dataspace;
    delete dataset;
    file.close();

  }// End of try block.

  // Catch failure caused by the H5File operations.
  catch (FileIException error) {
    error.printErrorStack();
    return -1;
  }

  // Catch failure caused by the DataSet operations.
  catch (DataSetIException error) {
    error.printErrorStack();
    return -1;
  }

  // Catch failure caused by the DataSpace operations.
  catch (DataSpaceIException error) {
    error.printErrorStack();
    return -1;
  }

  return 0; // Successfully terminated.

}
```

When I read the file using python I get:

```
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

As you can see, there is an extra "chunk" at the bottom full of zeros, that I don't want. I think this happens because I am extending the data set in each iteration. I have tried to set the initial data set dimensions to zero, i.e. `hsize_t dims[2] = {0,0};` thinking that in the beginning of the iteration, it will increase the dimensions of the data set and then write my data but I get the following instead.

`array([], shape=(20, 0), dtype=float64)`

Comment: We need to see your code so we can help you debug it.

Comment: You should create an extendible HDF5 dataset so that you can append data to it without overwriting existing data (with the help of hyperslabs).